# How to close parent form with child form on c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

When I press close button on child form that should close parent form with it.

Because of programming efficient I don't like to use form show() & hide() methods.(Instead I'm using showDialog() method)

Lets assume I have 3 forms

- form_A (my welcome form)
- form_B
- form_C.

From form_A I'll open form_B using `form_B.ShowDialog()` method. Then further I open form_C from form_B using `form_C.ShowDialog()` method.

My question is when I close form_C  using button click event, form_C and form_B should be closed and back to form_A. How could I do that?

Someone Please help me.

Comment: Please any code you have written

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//code in form A
formB.ShowDialog();
Close();
//code in form B
formC.ShowDialog();
Close();
```

So when closing `formC`, the `Close()` after will be executed and closes the current form which is `formB`. `formB` is closed -> the `Close()` after `formB.ShowDialog()` will be executed and that closes the current form which is `formA` and your `mainForm` will be shown again.

Comment: When formB is shown, formC won't be openen this way, Because ShowDialog will block the current method.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen the OP says the `formC` is shown by clicking some button on `formB`.

Comment: I read it as 1 method, you're right

Comment: Instead of close, I'd suggest setting dialogresult

Comment: @Sayse of course it will be used in case we need. The code I posted is just for simplicity and demonstrating the solution. if it's not `ShowDialog()` we would need more code with `FormClosed` and `FormClosing` events.

Comment: Yeah for simplicity I left out the need for a using block also, I agree

Comment: dialogresult fixed my problem. Thx @Sayse.